# C# Excel Addon - Compilation warning - Type library exporter could not find the type library for Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

How to fix this warning, pls?

```
Type library exporter could not find the type library for 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range'.  IUnknown was substituted for the interface.
```

The signature of the function is

```
public object[,] FUNCTION_XXX(Excel.Range range01, Excel.Range range02)
```

where

```
 using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function definition cannot accept Excel.Range but rather only object.

Thus replacement of the signature with

```
object[,] FUNCTION_XXX(object range01, object range02)
```

and then

casting these to `Excel.Range` solves the problem.

Comment: It is not a solution, merely a workaround.  There's something wrong with the Office PIA registration on your machine.  Other than just reinstalling it, try setting the assembly reference's Copy Local property to True.

Comment: I agree; I am trying to preserve the type library signature of an old COM component that uses Excel that I am rewriting in .NET.  I even tried generating some non PIA assemblies using tlbimp just to get the raw interface signatures, and still no luck.